# How to import tasks from OmniFocus into 2Do?

Tags: macos

Is there a way to import tasks from OmniFocus into [2Do](http://www.2doapp.com)?

Answer (score 1):

2Do currently has no import menu command, but you can use its URL schemes to create new tasks very flexibly. See [2Do URL Schemes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/224549/how-to-import-tasks-from-omnifocus-into-2do). You can use the [ofexport](https://github.com/psidnell/ofexport) package to get your tasks out of OmniFocus, and then use some Applscript magic to generate the URL schemes and send them to 2Do. I haven't done this yet myself but am considering it were I to move to 2Do. An example AppleScript that might help can be found [here](http://www.2doapp.com/applescript-mail-to-2do-create-task/).